# jQuery Dynamic Function and Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a function that handles the 'keyup' event for several input fields and passes the input value to a php script.  Here's the code I have so far

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#email").keyup(function () {

        val = $("input#email").val();
        what = 'email';

        aFunction(val, what);

    });

});

function aFunction(val, what) {

    var dataString = what + '=' + val;
    var error = "email_check";

    $.post("key.php", dataString, function (data) {
        //if (data.[error] == 'invalid'){
        if (data.email_check == 'invalid') {
            $("#ppp").html('error');
        } else {
            $("#ppp").html('good to go');
        }
    }, "json");

    //return false; 
}
```

When I uncomment

```
//if (data.[error] == 'invalid'){
```

and comment out

```
if (data.email_check == 'invalid'){
```

My the script doesnt execute and js file doesn't load into the firebug script console - I assume means there's an error because when I undo that and refresh I can view it. I've tried added single and double quotes to the variable.  Also, it would be helpful if there was a way to see what the is error is, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Mods - why do you keep editing my posts?  Am I doing something wrong, I cant see any changes?

Comment: I added the javascript tag to the question, as I saw the problem was just a syntax error. Is that ok?

Comment: No problem at all, I just thought I was making more work for you guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your primary problem here is that you should use either dot notation ("data.error") or array notation ("data['error']") but not both ("data.['error']").

Comment: It's actually called "bracket notation" ;)

Comment: ps - what's my secondary problem?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does not support braces in identifiers.

If the key is actually just `error`, you can write `if (data.error == 'invalid')`.
If it is `[error]`, you'll need to write `if (data['[error]'] == 'invalid`)`.

To see syntax errors, go to Firebug's Console tab.

Comment: +1 thanks for the heads up on console tab. I kept googling for 'validate jquery code' and it came back with links for the validator plugin